# Elastic Beanstalk not running strptime as expected

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am running python 3.6 on Elastic Beanstalk. The following error shows up when I try to use strptime:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-03-01 13:31:00 EST' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

Just from that error, you can see that the time data DOES match the format. Is there more to this than meets the eye? My code is as follows:

```
r['SCHEDULE_TIME'] = 2020-04-01 13:31:00 EST
scheduleTime = datetime.strptime(r['SCHEDULE_TIME'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

**EDIT:** This has to do with executing the python 3.6 version script in python 3.7. I need this to run in 3.6, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For those encountering this in the future, my solution was to pull the timezone out of the timestamp and set the tzinfo attribute of the datetime directly using replace(tzinfo=timezone_string_from_timestamp) after creating a datetime with the timestamp.